# How to append a copy of each element of a list to itself?

Tags: python, list, copy, append

I have a list of variables like

```
list = ["$res", "$hp", "def"]
```

etc. I want to append each element of that list to itself at the start with a hyphen preferably so it looks like,

```
list = ["$res - $res", "$hp - $hp", "$def - $def"]
```

How do I achieve this in python? I already have a function takes a list of variable setting code lines and strips them of all text besides the variables themselves. Now I want to combine it with a function that does this to prepare a list of variable names and their values on demand. This is all for some other program but I wanted to do the processing in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the formatted string for each values in the list to create the required values, you can achieve it using List-Comprehension:

```py
>>> lst = ["$res", "$hp", "$def"]
>>> [f"{x} - {x}" for x in lst]

['$res - $res', '$hp - $hp', '$def - $def']
```

Comment: What does the f before the xs in the loop do? Also it didn't work. I entered ```
print(vli)
[f"{x} - {x}" for x in vli]
print(vli)
``` and got the same result in both prints. I really can't edit this right.

Comment: nvm I got it to work. Just had to set the 2nd line as a variable and print that out. Still what does the f do?

Comment: @Felix `f""` is called a formatted string where any variable's value can be placed using curly braces `{}` more details at https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals